# Bezier curve calculate control points on a SVG-Path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to add a point into a SVG-Path at a certain position on the path.

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 48 241 C 50 13 129 26 130 238 C 138 521 214 431 220 228 C 237 65 288 -18 316 240" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>​
```

Furthermore, I would like to add a point in the Path (curve), so that the path (curve) doesn't deform.
The point is e.g. "C x1 y1 x2 y2 210 331".
My question:.
How can I determine the controls x1 y1 x2 y2?
E.g. "C 100 100 100 500 210 331" is wrong, because the curve will be deformed.

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d= "M 48 241 C 50 13 129 26 130 238 C 100 100 100 500 210 331 C 210 331 210 331 220 228 C 237 65 288 -18 316 240" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

In other words the point (x = 210, y = 331) is given. Wanted are controls "x1 y1 x2 y2".

[See here for more explanation](http://www.testen.pro/path/index.html)
(In order to add a graphic in “stackoverflow.com”, it is needed some points. But I haven’t enough points, therefore I inserted a link)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by deformed? Both of the curves look very similar to me.

Comment: What do you want the curve to look like?

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. What you are trying to achieve is not clear, however. Can you show an example of a non-distorted curve?

Comment: Though I don't understand the reason why you would do it (I suspect going to split the curve) but in the end you'd have to look up "cubic spline" (as that is what the C / c svg paths do) and then implement the calculation in javascript or look for an existing implementation...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. “Though I don't understand ... " Click here [Explanation](http://www.testen.pro/path/index.html) please to see my explanation. 
In order to add a graphic in “stackoverflow.com”, it is needed some points. But I haven’t enough points.